# Drools lhs how to create List

Tags: drools

How create list in Lhs?

```
dialect 'java'    
when    
....        
$tiers5: List() from Arrays.toList(new SomeClass(new BigDecimal(4000),null,5))      
....
then
```

I verify that instance of SameClass was created but next line doesn't launch.

I have tried myclass.getList(params) the same problem is occure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved to:

```
dialect 'java'    
when    
....        
$tiers5: List() from collect(SomeClass () from Arrays.toList(new SomeClass(new BigDecimal(4000),null,5)))
....
then
```